# Android: Should BroadcastReceiver or Wakefulintentservice end with finish()?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, commonsware-cwac

In my app I use alarm manager to set an alarm, which triggers a broadcast receiver, which starts Commonsware's Wakefulintentservice, which downloads some data.

My question is: should either the `BroadcastReceiver` or the `WakefulIntentService` or both or none of them end with the `finish()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finish()` is for stopping activities.  Services and broadcast receivers have their own lifecycles which handle it differently.